# Magento 2 free Testimonial

Tags: magento2

I have tried some free testimonial from marketplace.magento.com but none of them are working properly. Also searched in other places like github. Could you please let us know a good free magento 2 testimonial with good review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is free [Magento 2 Testimonials extension](https://www.yereone.com/testimonials-extension-for-magento-2/) by [Yereone](https://www.yereone.com/). It has bug-free code and looks really nice.